# opencv filtering/masking using a function

Tags: java, opencv

I want to threshold and RGB image with the rule: r>1.2g && r>1.2b

Is there any nice way to do it in opencv? Like some analog to python's filter()?

I'm using OpenCV for Java and writing it in pure java is pretty slow.

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV don't have specialized function to do this, so you will have to use combination of other OpenCV functions. I don't know whether it will be faster than hand written loop, but you can give it a try.

First approach is by using split() function. It will split 3-channel image into 3 one-channel images that you may compare in pretty straightforward way:

```
thresh = (r>1.2*g) & (r>1.2*b);
```

Of course this approach has the problem of copying data and allocating temporary memory for r, g and b images. Another trick that can be used will prevent memory allocations and copy of data but can be used only for images that are continuous in memory. It uses reshape() function. With it you can turn m*n 3-channel matrix into 3*(m*n) 1-channel matrix without copy of data. Than by calling column(0), column(1) and column(2) on this image you will have access to r, g and b images that you can compare in the same way as previously.

Sorry for giving only general directions and not providing code itself. I am not familiar with Java interface of OpenCV (only C++).